# How do I determine if a box intersects a mongoDB collection of boxes using geospacial method?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have figured out how to make the query for the intersection, but can't figure out how to define the boxes in the database so that it returns me all boxes that intersect with my query parameter.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this website to be most helpful. Just use their examples and everything should be clear. If not, consider turning that complex polygon into a square (which is also a polygin).

You can use these commands for a database called 'test' and collection called 'geo':

```
test.geo.insert( {_id: "Poly1", shape: {type: "Polygon", coordinates: [[ [1,2], [1,4], [4,4], [4,2], [1,2] ]] } });
test.geo.ensureIndex( {shape:"2dsphere"} );
geo.find( {shape: {$geoIntersects: {$geometry: {type: "Polygon", coordinates: [[ [2,4], [2,8], [3,8], [3,4], [2,4] ]] }}}} )
```

This particular example has the polygons intersecting on column 4. I have not yet tested all possible combinations but from the ones I tested, it does work.